# CSS all: revert still results in extension inheriting page styles?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I had understaood ([ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064172/how-to-isolate-a-div-from-public-css-styles); [ref 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)) that CSS's `all` property, when set to `revert`, would, in the case of an author stylesheet, isolate it from inheriting from other author stylesheets.

In other words, elements protected with this property/value would be fed the styles in the current stylesheet and only the initial, default styles fed by the user agent.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all), when `revert` is used in an author stylesheet it

> Rolls back the cascade to the user level, so that the
>   specified values are calculated as if no author-level rules were
>   specified for the element.

This doesn't seem to be the case for me, however. I have a Chrome extension which injects elements into a page, and I want to protect it from inheriting the webpage's styles.

CSS:

```
#guideo-tools, #guideo-tools * { all: revert; }
```

However, on the site shown in the pic it's inheriting box shadow on the buttons.

[image]

Have I misunderstood `all`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't misunderstood it, but the `revert` value for the `all` attribute is widely unsupported right now.

[From the Mozilla Developer page on revert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert):

[image]

I can also see this if I look at their example fiddle in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Interesting - I just figured that the latest Chrome supported pretty much everything :-P