# :not selector, style everything in the body except for

Tags: css, import, sass, css-selectors

Have an issue where a css framework imported into a scss file is clobbering the styles of the wysiwyg editor. Is there a way to import the framework and have it "skip" any element within a class or ID?

I've tried.. to no avail...

```
    // app.scss file

    body :not(#wysiwyg) {
      @import 'node_modules/some_css_framework.scss';
    }

    // also tried..
    body *:not(#wysiwyg) {
      @import 'node_modules/some_css_framework.scss';
    }
```

(Everything except for the #wysiwyg element, import and apply these styles..

Comment: Try without the `body` and `*` selectors, so just `:not(#wysiwyg)`

Comment: I don't think you can "unimport" your framework in that way. But there is an alternative - have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064172/how-to-isolate-a-div-from-public-css-styles), it might help.