# Html element which ignores all parent css

Tags: css, html, aspose.words

Im embeding a word document saved as html in my site,  but there are conflicts between the generated css and my site’s. What could really help me is having a “scoped” element, which is not effecting or being effected by the site itself. Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks

Comment: You could embed the word based html and its css in an iframe.

Comment: Use iframe tags

Comment: But an iframe is not very responsive - i might want to develop features which include access to the document from the outer site. All i need is the “scoped css” functionality

Answer (score 0):

I personally use classes as wrappers for scoping. Below all of the styles from the word document will be "scoped" to the beginning and ending of the span tag.

```css
/*some css wrapper class*/
.word-document-wrapper
{

}
```

```html
<span class="word-document-wrapper>

  <!--word document here-->

</span>
```

Comment: But how do u handle outer css effects on the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlSaveOptions class to specify additional options when saving a Word document into the Html, Mhtml or Epub format. For example:

```
Document doc = new Document("D:\\Temp\\input.docx");

HtmlSaveOptions opts = new HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Html);
opts.CssStyleSheetType = CssStyleSheetType.Embedded;
opts.ExportImagesAsBase64 = true;
opts.ExportFontsAsBase64 = true;
opts.PrettyFormat = true;

doc.Save("D:\\temp\\18.8.html", opts);
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: That will work on the inside css not affecting the rest of the document, but what about the other way around? Lets say i have a css rule that makes all divs rtl, which is ok for my site but problematic for the embeded document

Comment: We are checking this scenario and will get back to you soon.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to isolate CSS styles of a HTML element from styles of the containing document is to manually reset all unwanted CSS styles on the element. Please check [How To Isolate a div from public CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064172/how-to-isolate-a-div-from-public-css-styles)