# Exclude some selectors from a global dark theme

Tags: css, sass, tippyjs

I have this .scss rule that applies a global dark theme.

```
#app.dark-theme {
  // LOTS of rules...
}
```

I've decided that opposite-themed tooltips look better. Instead of dark theme tooltips on dark theme #app, I like light theme tooltips on dark theme #app, and dark theme tooltips on light theme #app.

And here lies the problem... the dark theme rules I've declared are affecting tooltips. I need to somehow make every rule inside `#app.dark-theme` NOT apply to tooltips. Here's the tooltip selector

```css
// Tippys can be appended anywhere in the dom, including as a direct child
// of <body>, which is the parent of #app.

#app div[data-tippy-root], // add specificity for tippys inside #app
div[data-tippy-root] {
  // tippy css
}
```

I've tried this [How To Isolate a div from public CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064172/how-to-isolate-a-div-from-public-css-styles)

But it unsets ALL styles. I still want the tippy CSS, and Bulma CSS, to apply to the tooltip. I just don't want my dark theme CSS to affect tooltips.

I've also tried using the `:not()` selector, but it doesn't seem suited for this use case.

```
#app.dark-theme :not(div[data-tippy-root]) {
 // of course it's not this easy :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variables, take a look at an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/vk61pjdq/)

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #24242b;
}

html[data-theme="dark"] {
  --primary-color: #f89898;
}


a {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}
```