# How to make a div have a separate dom just like when you use IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

when ever we load something with an iframe , everything loads in its seperate dom root.

so thats great one iframes css,js dont get affected by existing stuff on the page .

I was wondering is there a way to  create a div  but have that div stay in it's own dom document root without using an iframe ?

so fore example i can place htm css js in that div but because it would run like an iframe and run in its own dom document root.

can this be done ?  or is just using iframes is the only way.

```
     <iframe rel="prerender"  src="https://www.mypage.com/custom.html" > 
   </iframe>
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) they use shadow dom which encapsulates styles. Encapsulating JS is not possible with this but shouldn't be needed anyhow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly can I replace an iframe with a div and Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040297/how-exactly-can-i-replace-an-iframe-with-a-div-and-javascript)

Comment: please explain little more or give any example so that it will be easy for us

Comment: Well when you use pjax ,  js and css dont get re initialized  you have to manually  reinitialize it in every single page .  I guess there is no solution to this . and no jd this is not a duplicate there is a difference in this question of having elements run in there own seperate dom roots just like iframe does, key word dom root  ..  the good example of runing elements in own seperate dom roots is using 5 or 6 iframes . but thats not good  hence the initial reason  for asking this question.